# Can an HTTP request be made to a transparent proxy and receive the response from the upstream server instead?

Tags: networking, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, squid

I have a setup where A (the client) makes an HTTP request to B (a fully transparent proxy server) which redirects the request to C and redirects responses from C to A.

Is it possible to have C reply directly to A without going through B?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

There is an optional HTTP request header field called ["X-Forwarded-For"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) that some proxy servers will inject into an HTTP request before forwarding it to the destination server. You'd have to check the particular proxy server and it's configuration to know if it does this. The field is supposed to contain the IP address of the actual originator of the request. I have personally used it for accurate geolocation of website visitors, but I'm sure there are other uses as well.

Regardless, because HTTP functions on top of TCP, rather than a connectionless protocol like UDP, Point C would still have to establish a brand new connection with Point A...which probably won't happen unless Point A is mysteriously listening for one. Even if it knew Point A's IP address.